# Basic combinatorics question - christmas presents

Tags: combinatorics

Each of 10 employees brings one (distinct) present to an ofﬁce party. Each present is given to a randomly selected employee by Santa (an employee can get more than one present). What is the probability that at least two employees receive no presents?

I was thinking about tackling this as a, "find the inverse" type problem, where the inverse is: what is the probability that at least 9 employees receive at least 1 present. So I do stars and bars w/ 9 fixed stars... which is C(1 + 10 - 1, 1) which is nonsense. Help!

Note: the answer, which I don't understand, is 1−(10!−10×9×10!/2!)/10^(10).

Comment: Note that stars and bars tells you the number of outcomes but does not return equally likely outcomes.  Take a smaller example, two people and two presents.  Stars and bars will tell you there are three ways for the presents to be distributed, namely $[\star\star][~],~~[~][\star\star],$ and $[\star][\star]$.  What it doesn't tell you is that $[\star][\star]$ is twice as likely to occur as the others.

Answer (score 2):

As each present can be given to $10$ employees independently, there are $10^{10}$ ways to give out the presents to the employees.  Do you know which of the $10$s is the number of employees and which is the number of presents?  You are correct that it is easier to count how many of these give presents to $9$ or $10$ employees.  For $10$ you can just line the employees up, then each ordering of the presents in a row, of which there are $10!$, gives a present to each employee.  For $9$, you have $10$ ways to pick the person who gets two, $10 \choose 2$ ways to select the two they get, then add an empty box to the remaining eight and distribute them to the $9$ remaining employees in $9!$ ways.  So the number of ways to give the presents to $9$ or $10$ different employees is $10^{10}+10{10\choose 2}9!$

Comment: This makes sense, but I can't reconcile it with what this term should be according to the answer, which says it should be (10!−10×9×10!/2!).

Comment: The two agree.  ${10 \choose 2}=\frac {10 \cdot 9}2$ and $10 \cdot 9!=10!$